# Дублирование строк при использовании связи ManyToMany и Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

есть сущности Person и Address, между ними связь ManyToMany

но при сохранении используя репозитории spring data jpa, в таблице persons_addresses почему-то все строки связей сохраняются дважды

Собственно вопрос, почему так происходит, что я делаю неправильно?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String fullName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "persons_addresses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"))
    private List<Address> addresses;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String addressName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "persons_addresses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"))
    private List<Person> persons;
}
```

// use in service with transactional

```
@Transactional
public PersonDto create(PersonDto newPerson) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setFullName(newPerson.getFullName());

    person.setAddresses(new ArrayList<>());
    newPerson.getAddresses().forEach(a -> {
        Address address = addressRepository.findByAddressName(a);
        if (address == null) {
            address = new Address();
            address.setAddressName(a);
            address.setPersons(new ArrayList<>());
        }
        address.getPersons().add(person);
        addressRepository.save(address);
        person.getAddresses().add(address);
    });
    return new PersonDto(personRepository.save(person));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JoinTable` нужно указывать только на одном конце ассоциации. На том, который будет ею управлять. В вашем случаее это имеет смысл сделать в Person.

Сейчас из-за того, что `@JoinTable` и там и там запись в таблицу ассоциации сохраняется и при сохранении `Person` и при сохранении `Address`. Правильно так:

```
public class Person {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "persons_addresses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"))
    private List<Address> addresses;
}
public class Address {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="addresses")
    private List<Person> persons;
}
```

`mappedBy` указывает, что другой конец (т.е. Person) является владельцем и управляет ассоциацией (т.е. создает записи при сохранении и т.д.).

Для упрощения работы с ассоциацией и поддержания консистентности объектов в памяти часто еще создают метод:

```
class Person {
     public void addAddress(Address address) {
        this.addresses.add(address);
        address.getPersons().add(this);
     }
}
```